# Problems accessing samba share from sharepoint web part

Tags: sharepoint, authentication, samba

I'm using System.IO.File.Copy to copy a file from the local windows/sharepoint server to a samba share. But I'm getting an exception:

```
Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password.
:    at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
  at System.IO.File.InternalCopy(String sourceFileName, String destFileName, Boolean overwrite)
  at System.IO.File.Copy(String sourceFileName, String destFileName, Boolean overwrite)
```

The user that I'm logged on does indeed have access to that share. I.e. I can manually map a drive to it from the local sharepoint server.

If I also give the service account under which sharepoint is running access to the share, the System.IO.File.Copy operation works ok.

From the Samba logs I found out that sharepoint/windows is not passing my username to Samba. See: (check_ntlm_password:  Checking password for unmapped user [][]@[FODV-SHRPT-01] ) under the FAILED log below.

(I believe these are the relevant parts of the samba logs) 1st the successful one for the service account with elevated privileges, 2nd failed one for my login:

If anyone could shed some light on this I'd be ever so grateful.
SUCCESSFUL:

```
 get_dc_list: preferred server list: "COPP-DC-01, copp-dc-01"
[2011/11/02 11:01:27, 3] libsmb/namequery_dc.c:rpc_dc_name(117)
  rpc_dc_name: Returning DC COPP-DC-01 (172.16.11.205) for domain OAKS
[2011/11/02 11:01:27, 3] libsmb/cliconnect.c:cli_start_connection(1417)
  Connecting to host=COPP-DC-01
[2011/11/02 11:01:27, 3] lib/util_sock.c:open_socket_out(874)
  Connecting to 172.16.11.205 at port 445
[2011/11/02 11:01:27, 3] rpc_client/cli_pipe.c:rpc_pipe_bind(2081)
  rpc_pipe_bind: Remote machine COPP-DC-01 pipe \lsarpc fnum 0x8005 bind request returned ok.
[2011/11/02 11:01:27, 3] rpc_parse/parse_lsa.c:lsa_io_sec_qos(224)
  lsa_io_sec_qos: length c does not match size 8
[2011/11/02 11:01:27, 3] auth/auth.c:check_ntlm_password(221)
  check_ntlm_password:  Checking password for unmapped user [OAKS]\[dev_shrpt_app]@[FODV-SHRPT-01] with the new password interface
[2011/11/02 11:01:27, 3] auth/auth.c:check_ntlm_password(224)
  check_ntlm_password:  mapped user is: [OAKS]\[dev_shrpt_app]@[FODV-SHRPT-01]
[2011/11/02 11:01:27, 3] smbd/sec_ctx.c:push_sec_ctx(208)
  push_sec_ctx(0, 0) : sec_ctx_stack_ndx = 1
[2011/11/02 11:01:27, 3] smbd/uid.c:push_conn_ctx(345)
  push_conn_ctx(0) : conn_ctx_stack_ndx = 0
[2011/11/02 11:01:27, 3] smbd/sec_ctx.c:set_sec_ctx(241)
  setting sec ctx (0, 0) - sec_ctx_stack_ndx = 1
[2011/11/02 11:01:27, 3] smbd/sec_ctx.c:pop_sec_ctx(339)
  pop_sec_ctx (0, 0) - sec_ctx_stack_ndx = 0
[2011/11/02 11:01:27, 3] libsmb/namequery.c:get_dc_list(1426)
  get_dc_list: preferred server list: "COPP-DC-01, copp-dc-01"
[2011/11/02 11:01:27, 3] libsmb/namequery_dc.c:rpc_dc_name(117)
  rpc_dc_name: Returning DC COPP-DC-01 (172.16.11.205) for domain OAKS
[2011/11/02 11:01:27, 3] libsmb/cliconnect.c:cli_start_connection(1417)
  Connecting to host=COPP-DC-01
[2011/11/02 11:01:27, 3] lib/util_sock.c:open_socket_out(874)
  Connecting to 172.16.11.205 at port 445
[2011/11/02 11:01:27, 3] rpc_client/cli_pipe.c:rpc_pipe_bind(2081)
  rpc_pipe_bind: Remote machine COPP-DC-01 pipe \NETLOGON fnum 0x8016 bind request returned ok.
[2011/11/02 11:01:27, 3] rpc_client/cli_pipe.c:rpc_pipe_bind(2081)
  rpc_pipe_bind: Remote machine COPP-DC-01 pipe \NETLOGON fnum 0x8017 bind request returned ok.
[2011/11/02 11:01:27, 3] auth/auth.c:check_ntlm_password(270)
  check_ntlm_password: winbind authentication for user [dev_shrpt_app] succeeded
```

FAILED:

```
[2011/11/02 11:05:36, 3] libsmb/namequery.c:get_dc_list(1426)
  get_dc_list: preferred server list: "COPP-DC-01, copp-dc-01"
[2011/11/02 11:05:36, 3] libsmb/namequery_dc.c:rpc_dc_name(117)
  rpc_dc_name: Returning DC COPP-DC-01 (172.16.11.205) for domain OAKS
[2011/11/02 11:05:36, 3] libsmb/cliconnect.c:cli_start_connection(1417)
  Connecting to host=COPP-DC-01
[2011/11/02 11:05:36, 3] lib/util_sock.c:open_socket_out(874)
  Connecting to 172.16.11.205 at port 445
[2011/11/02 11:05:36, 3] rpc_client/cli_pipe.c:rpc_pipe_bind(2081)
  rpc_pipe_bind: Remote machine COPP-DC-01 pipe \lsarpc fnum 0x8016 bind request returned ok.
[2011/11/02 11:05:36, 3] rpc_parse/parse_lsa.c:lsa_io_sec_qos(224)
  lsa_io_sec_qos: length c does not match size 8
[2011/11/02 11:05:36, 3] auth/auth.c:check_ntlm_password(221)
  check_ntlm_password:  Checking password for unmapped user []\[]@[FODV-SHRPT-01] with the new password interface
[2011/11/02 11:05:36, 3] auth/auth.c:check_ntlm_password(224)
  check_ntlm_password:  mapped user is: [OAKS]\[]@[FODV-SHRPT-01]
[2011/11/02 11:05:36, 3] smbd/sec_ctx.c:push_sec_ctx(208)
  push_sec_ctx(0, 0) : sec_ctx_stack_ndx = 1
[2011/11/02 11:05:36, 3] smbd/uid.c:push_conn_ctx(345)
  push_conn_ctx(0) : conn_ctx_stack_ndx = 0
[2011/11/02 11:05:36, 3] smbd/sec_ctx.c:set_sec_ctx(241)
  setting sec ctx (0, 0) - sec_ctx_stack_ndx = 1
[2011/11/02 11:05:36, 3] smbd/sec_ctx.c:pop_sec_ctx(339)
  pop_sec_ctx (0, 0) - sec_ctx_stack_ndx = 0
[2011/11/02 11:05:36, 3] auth/auth.c:check_ntlm_password(270)
  check_ntlm_password: guest authentication for user [] succeeded
[2011/11/02 11:05:36, 3] smbd/sec_ctx.c:push_sec_ctx(208)
SNIP
SNIP
SNIP  
[2011/11/02 11:05:36, 3] smbd/connection.c:yield_connection(69)
  Yielding connection to expest
[2011/11/02 11:05:36, 3] smbd/error.c:error_packet(146)
  error packet at smbd/reply.c(676) cmd=117 (SMBtconX) NT_STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE
[2011/11/02 11:05:36, 3] smbd/process.c:process_smb(1110)
  Transaction 4 of length 43
[2011/11/02 11:05:36, 3] smbd/process.c:switch_message(914)
  switch message SMBulogoffX (pid 3748242) conn 0x0
[2011/11/02 11:05:36, 3] smbd/sec_ctx.c:set_sec_ctx(241)
  setting sec ctx (0, 0) - sec_ctx_stack_ndx = 0
[2011/11/02 11:05:36, 3] smbd/reply.c:reply_ulogoffX(1618)
  ulogoffX vuid=101
[2011/11/02 11:05:36, 3] smbd/process.c:timeout_processing(1359)
  timeout_processing: End of file from client (client has disconnected).
[2011/11/02 11:05:36, 3] smbd/sec_ctx.c:set_sec_ctx(241)
  setting sec ctx (0, 0) - sec_ctx_stack_ndx = 0
[2011/11/02 11:05:36, 3] smbd/connection.c:yield_connection(69)
  Yielding connection to 
[2011/11/02 11:05:36, 3] smbd/server.c:exit_server_common(675)
  Server exit (normal exit)
```

Answer (score 0):

[Double hop issue](http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/archive/2008/08/22/iis-windows-authentication-and-the-double-hop-issue.aspx)? Otherwise it is an issue with your SharePoint code not running under the context of the user.

SharePoint will impersonate the user unless you are inside an [SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spsecurity.runwithelevatedprivileges.aspx) delegate.